# Говорили о погоде, о природе (,/,-) в общем, ни о чём

Tags: пунктуация

Говорили о погоде, о природе (?) в общем, ни о чём.

На месте вопросительного знака должно быть "-" или ", - "?

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Говорили о погоде, о природе - в общем, ни о чём.

Это тема "Вводные слова  (В ОБЩЕМ, СЛОВОМ, ОДНИМ СЛОВОМ, КОРОЧЕ ГОВОРЯ)  перед обобщающим словом, стоящим после однородного ряда". Согласно правилу, при наличии  вводных слов тире ставится перед вводным словом, а после вводного слова ставится запятая.

Запятую и тире можно встретить в старых текстах (до 1956 год), также в качестве авторского знака (обычно при значительной распространенности ряда).

ПРИМЕРЫ

Понимаете, алебарды, секиры, катапульты, греческий огонь, ятаганы, ― в общем, средневекового реквизита в Голливуде хватит. [И. А. Ильф, Е. П. Петров. Колумб причаливает к берегу (1936)]

Внешние факты для него только статив, только экран, только сосуд ― словом, только средство. [Л. Д. Троцкий]

Это заметно было и по поведению немцев, которые шумно бегали по лесу, пилили деревья, рубили ветки на топливо, раскидывали палатки ― одним словом, делали всё то, что люди делают на новом месте. [Э. Г. Казакевич. Звезда (1946)]

Comment: Вся штука в том, что "в общем" не является тут "обобщающим". У него значение "по существу", "в сущности". Т.е. "обобщающими словами" можно назвать всю конструкцию "в общем, ни о чем". И внутри этой конструкции "в общем" требует запятой, как тут и сказано. А будь "в общем" ***обобщающим***  словом то как раз появился бы мотив для первой запятой - перед тире, но тогда не нужна бы была запятая после обобщающего слова. Т.е. вы верно выбрали вариант, но совершенно неправильно его обосновали. Вводное слово и обобщающее - это очень разные вещи...

Comment: Сравните пример из Толстого - вот там типичное обобщающее "везде". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE Я так это понимаю.

Comment: В общем - это именно вводное слово, обобщающим словом является "ни о чём". Обобщающее слово имеет тот же падеж, что и весь ряд (предложный в данном случае). Вводное слово "в общем" без труда заменяется синонимами "словом", "одним словом".

Comment: Подождите. "В общем" - воодное. Ладно, согласен. К какой части предложения оно относится? Вы согласны, что вводное должно принадлежать к какой-то части? Согласны, что здесь это часть "ни о чем"? Вводное по всем правилам внутри предложения обособляться запятыми с двух сторон (если только оно не внутри скобок или кавычек).  Где запятая перед *в общем*?! )))    Не ищите, я понимаю, что она там не нужна, но по вашей логике получается самостоятельный мотив для запятой перед тире. Вот и объясните, почему её там нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если обобщающее слово стоит после однородных членов, то перед ним ставится тире. Запятая ниоткуда не следует.

Comment: "пишется слитно: вообщем." never! Jamais! Никогда! )))) http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E2%EE%EE%E1%F9%E5%EC&

Comment: Ужас! Как вдолбили мне в младшей школе, так почти полвека пишу это слово, оказывается, неправильно :-0

Comment: Вы просто спутали две разные вещи. Очень частая ошибка, почему я так быстро и среагировал. Очень может быть, что в школе вам, как и большинству наших ровесников, просто сказали не сказали, как не надо (была такая "советская" мода, ошибки не демонстрировали явно, чтобы случайно не отложилось в памяти в качестве верного). А вышло-то как раз наоборот.

Comment: Таки не спутал. Очень хорошо помню, как долго ломали моё сопротивление снижением оценки за "в общем", пока не приучили. Не, я не злопамятный. Просто злой и на память не жалуюсь ))))

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу здесь причин для запятой с тире: ни как для единого знака, ни как для двух самостоятельных. Здесь надо выбирать между запятой и тире, поскольку есть только один мотив - присоединительная (или как там её называют - посмотрю точно потом) конструкция "в общем". Лучше обычное тире.

***Говорили о погоде, о природе - в общем, ни о чём.***

Хотя лично мне в "авторской" пунктуации подошло бы скорее

***Говорили о погоде, о природе, в общем - ни о чём.***

Меня за подобные вольности часто критикуют, но я не вижу формальных причин запрещать такое выразительное написание. Подчеркивается акцент на "ни о чем"

Answer (score 1):

> На месте вопросительного знака должно быть "-" или ", - "?

Я бы выбрал или тире (*"Говорили о погоде, о природе - в общем, ни о чём"*), или многоточие:

***Говорили о погоде, о природе... в общем - ни о чём.***